# How to store a smart pointer to map of string to member function in a class so that it doesn't fail due to an incomplete type?

Tags: c++, c++11, types, smart-pointers

---

**Background**

---

I have been writing a StateMachine whose transition table is loaded at runtime. The action to take upon each transition is stored as a string. The string is converted to a `std::function` object that points to a member function of the state machine class. When an event occurs, and results in a transition, that function is invoked.

---

**Problem**

---

I have successfully used this strategy before to decide which function is called at run time. Unfortunately, I've been running into the following error:

`error: return type 'XStMachine::TrFunc {aka class std::function<void (XStMachine::*)(const EventData&)>}' is incomplete`

Or

`invalid use of incomplete type`

---

**Steps Taken**

---

1. I consulted Google and Stackoverflow. I got a number of ideas including taking the definition out of the place where the type is incomplete. Unfortunately, I couldn't get it to work successfully.
2. I tried using a raw pointer instead of a `unique_ptr` and found that things worked magically.
3. I ended up reading a little on the difference between how `shared_ptr` and `unique_ptr` handle incomplete types. I tried a shared_ptr, but that did not solve my issue either.
4. I tried creating a `friend` class to my state machine in the hope that by the time of the friend class' declaration, the type would be considered whole. I could not get this to work.
5. Finally, I created the following minimal example (Uncomment code to reproduce the error, please.) which demonstrates the problems I ran into: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/791092c7ca8fff24 and came to the experts! :)

---

**Source Code**

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
#include <map>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

struct EventData
{
    unsigned int x;
};

class Friendly; // Required for compiling the code. Why?

class XStMachine
{
        friend class Friendly;
        unique_ptr<Friendly> fPtr;   //-- Doesn't compile if Friendly is not fwd. declared
        unsigned int y;
        unsigned int z;
    public:
        typedef void(XStMachine::*TrFuncPtr)(EventData const&);
        typedef std::function<TrFuncPtr> TrFunc;
    private:
        // map<string, TrFunc> fMap; //-- Doesn't compile because TrFunc is incomplete
        // unique_ptr<map<string, TrFunc>> fMap; // Doesn't compile; incomplete type.
        map<string, TrFunc> *fMap;  // Compiles with incomplete type.
    protected:
        void tranFunc1(EventData const &d)
        {
            y = d.x;
        }

        void tranFunc2(EventData const &d)
        {
            z = d.x;    
        }
    public:
        XStMachine()
        {
            // Code to init fMap
        }

        // The code below doesn't compile. incomplete type.
        TrFunc getTranFunc(std::string const &s)
        {
            return (*fMap)[s];
        }

        ~XStMachine()
        {
        }
};

class Friendly
{
    // unique_ptr<map<string, XStMachine::TrFunc> fMap; // Doesn't compile, the type is incomplete. 
    public:
        Friendly()
        {
            // Code to allocate and init fMap
        }

        // Dosen't compile if defined here because the return type is incomplete.
        //XStMachine::TrFunc& getTranFunc(std::string const&)
        //{
            // return (*fMap)[s];
        //}
};
// The type is incomplete -> Will this work inside a separate cpp file?
//XStMachine::TrFunc& getTranFunc(std::string const &s)
//{
    // Weird - Can't access protected members though we're friends. :/
    /*
    static map<string, XStMachine::TrFunc> fMap = {{"tranFunc1", function(&XStMachine::tranFunc1)},
                                                   {"tranFunc2", function(&XStMachine::tranFunc2)}
                                                  };     
    */
    //return fMap[s];
//}

int main() {
    cout << "I need to understand incomplete types." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

---

**Full Error Output from Coliru (gcc 6.3, C++ 14)**

---

```
main.cpp: In member function 'XStMachine::TrFunc XStMachine::getTranFunc(const string&)':
main.cpp:48:3: error: return type 'XStMachine::TrFunc {aka class std::function<void (XStMachine::*)(const EventData&)>}' is incomplete
   {
   ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:64:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/ios:40,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/stl_pair.h: In instantiation of 'struct std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::function<void (XStMachine::*)(const EventData&)> >':
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/stl_map.h:481:10:   required from 'std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type& std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[](const key_type&) [with _Key = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _Tp = std::function<void (XStMachine::*)(const EventData&)>; _Compare = std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::function<void (XStMachine::*)(const EventData&)> > >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type = std::function<void (XStMachine::*)(const EventData&)>; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]'
main.cpp:49:23:   required from here
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/stl_pair.h:196:11: error: 'std::pair<_T1, _T2>::second' has incomplete type
       _T2 second;                /// @c second is a copy of the second object
           ^~~~~~
In file included from main.cpp:3:0:
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/functional:1526:11: note: declaration of 'class std::function<void (XStMachine::*)(const EventData&)>'
     class function;
           ^~~~~~~~
```

---

**Objectives**

---

*Primary*: Understand what is going on in the example code and fix it.

*Secondary*: Gain a clear understanding of what an incomplete type is so that I can:
   * Solve related problems in the future.
   * Know if it is safe to override unique_ptr's default deleter with a deleter that calls the default.

My lack of understanding is really getting in my way here.

---

**Related Questions**

---

1. Even though `Friendly` is declared as a friend within `XStMachine` in the example code, it has to be forward declared earlier in the program as well. Why does this happen?
2. Even though `Friendly` is declared a friend, it cannot access protected member functions of `XStMachine`. For instance, `&XStMachine::tranFunc1` is invalid. Why?

Comment: You should be experienced enough to know that we need the *whole* error output (including any possible informational notes), together with the code that causes the error *in the question itself*.

Comment: The code that causes the error in question is [linked in the body](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/791092c7ca8fff24) of my question is there any reason that it is not sufficient? I will share a more detailed error output, though I haven't really snipped out much. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: @batbrat _"is there any reason that it is not sufficient?"_ Yes, your question needs to be self contained. If the code is too long, narrow it down to a [MCVE] that reproduces the error.

Comment: Think about what happens if the link goes stale, if the destination disappears. Then your question becomes worthless.

Comment: you may define `TrFunc` as `typedef std::function<void(EventData const&)> TrFunc`. when assigning member functions to it, you can use `std::bind` or a lambda.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I have built what I believe to be a minimal, complete and verifiable example of the problem that shows two of the approaches I attempted. I'll simply add that in to the question. I thought it wise to keep the question body as short as possible, so I left the body in the link. In retrospect, that's not a good idea.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, πάνταῥεῖ, thanks for helping me improve. Have some upvotes! :)

Comment: @pergy, I apologize for the delay in replying. I was trying to understand the approach you suggested. The function type you specified is not incomplete, and I could use std::bind at the time of assignment, so that would mean no more problems. Have I understood right?

Comment: @batbrat yes, this is what i meant!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::function` takes only a regular function type as template argument. A pointer-to-member-function type doesn't work.

Below is what might be a typical definition of `std::function` in the standard library:

```
template< class >
class function; // intentionally undefined 
template< class R, class... Args >
class function<R(Args...)> // actual definition
```

The template argument doesn't determine what kind of function this instantiation can store, but rather *how this instantiation can be called*.

Any instantiation attempt with a type that is not a regular function type will produce an incomplete type. Example:

```
std::function <int> incomplete;
```

In your code you may either:

- store `std::function<void(EventData const&)>` in the map (use `std::bind` to construct these objects from a pointer-to-member-function and an object pointer); or
- do away with `std::function` altogether and store pointers-to-member-function in the map directly.

Comment: Changing the template parameter does indeed stop the 'incomplete type' problem. Combining your suggestion with std::bind as @pergy's suggestion to use std::bind fixed the issue for me. EDIT: I just saw that you've suggested the same. Thanks!

Comment: `std::function` is declared as you said so that only the specialization which is a callable is ever instantiated, right? This will ensure that the callable 'concept' is not violated, if I understand correctly.

Comment: What is the problem with this definition? Do you understand *why* std::function is needed? How would you define it in a way that fulfills the purpose?

Comment: "so that only the specialization which is a callable is ever instantiated," basically yes, this is correct.

Comment: As I understand it, std::function is a wrapper around anything that can be called in C++; do correct me if I'm wrong. As for the main purpose, I'm afraid I don't know. I'd rather not waste your time, so could you please point me toward a resource you like that I can use in addition to my Google searches?

Comment: You are right. The purpose is to wrap different callable things (non-member functions, member functions and function objects) in a unified interface.